# Importing node modules from root directory using es6 and babel-node

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm writing a node app with es6 using babel transpiler.

I have 2 files `index.js` & `my-module.js` on my root directory

```
- index.js
- my-module.js
```

my-module.js

```
export let myFunc = () => {
  console.log('myFunc was called!!!');
}
```

index.js

```
import {myFunc} from './my-module';
myFunc();
```

if I run the following line from the command line everything works as expected.

```
$ babel-node index.js >> myFunc was called!!!
```

but if I remove the dot when importing my-module:

```
import {myFunc} from '/my-module';
myFunc();
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/my-module'
```

Any reason why I can't import modules using an absolute path? anyway to change .babelrc config to support it?

Thanks

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Like (almost) any tool '/x' means 'x' in the root of your filesystem. Babel doesn't actually look at the paths, it just compiles

```
import {myFunc} from '/my-module';
```

into

```
var _myModule = require('/my-module');
```

And node actually looks up the module.

---

If you really want to import relative to the root of the project, you could use a plugin. I recommend using something that isn't very ambiguous, and make sure you document this for the next person reading your code!

Here's an example where we use a leading `~` to mean project relative. You could use anything you like e.g. `^` would also be good.

Example Input:

```
import {a} from '~my-module';
import {b} from '/my-module';
import {c} from './my-module';
```

scripts/babel-plugin-project-relative-require.js

```
module.exports = function (babel) {
  // get the working directory
  var cwd = process.cwd();

  return new babel.Transformer("babel-plugin-project-relative-require", {
    ImportDeclaration: function(node, parent) {
      // probably always true, but let's be safe
      if (!babel.types.isLiteral(node.source)) {
        return node;
      }

      var ref = node.source.value;

      // ensure a value, make sure it's not home relative e.g. ~/foo
      if (!ref || ref[0] !== '~' || ref[1] === '/') {
        return node;
      }

      node.source.value = cwd + '/' + node.source.value.slice(1);

      return node;
    }
  });
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "./scripts/babel-plugin-project-relative-require.js"
    ]
}
```

Output (if run in /tmp):

```
'use strict';

var _tmpMyModule = require('/tmp/my-module');

var _myModule = require('/my-module');

var _myModule2 = require('./my-module');
```

Comment: btw when running your attached plugin I get the following:

TypeError: The plugin "./scripts/babel-plugin-project-relative-require.js" didn't export a Plugin instance

Comment: @Gavriguy update babel? Make sure the local and global versions are up to date, `npm i -g babel@latest; npm i -D babel-core@latest`

Comment: Once I packaged the plugin as a node module ( ` npm install https://github.com/gavriguy/babel-plugin-project-relative-require.git --save` ) it works like a charm. much appreciated @FakeRainBrigand

Answer (score 41):

The solution from FakeRainBrigand/Gavriguy is good and works well.
So i decided to develop a plugin which you can easily install with npm in and use a simple Babel-Plugin.

https://github.com/michaelzoidl/babel-root-import

Hope this helps...

Comment: This plugin has some troubles working on Windows given the sourcePath of windows operating systems. On Linux it works fine thought

Comment: Check again :) We support windows since the last release \o/

Answer (score 7):

First of all, Babel is just a transpiler from ES2015 to ES5 syntax. Its job is to transpile this:

```
import {myFunc} from '/my-module'
```

into this:

```
var _myModule = require('/my-module');
```

Actual module requiring performed by Node, and how Node does it you can read in details here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules

To summary, `./module` means path to module relative to local directory, `/module` is an absolute path to module, `module` triggers Node to look for module in local `node_modules` directory and all ascending.